# How to add single word invocation (not invocation name) to Alexa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I read in [How to add single word invocation name alexa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535922/how-to-add-single-word-invocation-name-alexa) that we can still use a single word invocation while our skill is in development (not published).  Where on the console specifically do I define my single word invocation (not invocation name)?  Is is the same as the Skill name?

Answer (score 1):

Skill name is not the invocation name. You can only choose the skill name once but you can change the invocation name.

The invocation name can be changed in the console in:

- Build -> Invocation -> Skill Invocation Name

But keep in mind that your "single word invocation " and invocation name are the same.
See the rules when you are allowed to use one word as invocation name.
E.g. [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/106773/are-one-word-invocation-names-allowed.html)